# How do I switch terminals in Visual Studio code using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to be able to switch between terminal panes in VSCode using a keyboard shortcut. I am on a Mac.

I have opened keyboard shortcuts (Commandkey+K, Commandkey+S) and found the `workbench.action.terminal.focusNextPane` setting:
[image]

where it states quite clearly what the keyboard shortcut should be (option+command+downarrow or option+command+leftarrow) but neither of those work. They DO work when focus is in the editor and I want to switch between panes there, but not working when the focus in the terminal.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I hope I'm missing something obvious. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Are your terminals split or are they just two different terminals?  The commands you are trying to use are just for moving between split terminal panes - not to go to the next terminal.  That command is `workbench.action.terminal.focusNext` and is not bound to a keybinding by default.

Comment: aha, brilliant, thank you, I WAS missing something obvious. `workbench.action.terminal.focusNext` was the correct one and I followed the suggested keybinding here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/37937#issuecomment-343231679, making sure to set the when expression to `terminalFocus`. If you write your comment as an answer I shall accept it as such. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commands you are looking at (`Terminal: Focus Next Pane` and `Terminal: Focus Previous Pane`) are to switch between split terminal panes.

The commands to switch between terminals are:

```
Terminal: Focus Next Terminal
  workbench.action.terminal.focusNext

Terminal: Focus Previous Terminal
  workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious
```

both of which are unbound by default.

Comment: thanks. I bound them to cmd+shift+j, cmd+shift+k as suggested here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/37937#issuecomment-343231679